# Request Matcher not resolved while migrating spring security from 3 to 4

Tags: spring, security, migrate

I am migrating my spring security from 3.1.4 to 4.1.5. I am using RequestMatcher in my security config to filter out urls.I updated RequestMatcher to the correct package as suggested in Migration document to org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher.

I am pointing request-matcher-ref in  to point the a custom class which implements RequestMatcher. But i am getting the following error in intellij - Cannot resolve required base class 'org.springframework.security.web.util.RequestMatcher'.
How to resolve this issue.

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

<security:debug/>

<bean id="preflightRequestMatcher" class="com.genesyslab.rcs.security.RequestMethodMatcher">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="OPTIONS"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="regularRequestMatcher" class="com.genesyslab.rcs.security.RequestMethodMatcher">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="OPTIONS"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="false"/>
</bean>


<security:http auto-config="false" create-session="never" request-matcher-ref="preflightRequestMatcher" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/contact-centers/*/user-recordings/*/play/**" security="none" auto-config="false" create-session="always"/>
<security:http pattern="/contact-centers/*/user-screen-recordings/*/play/**" security="none" auto-config="false" create-session="always"/>

<security:http auto-config="false" create-session="always" request-matcher-ref="regularRequestMatcher">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginsession" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutsession" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/keepalivesession" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/recordings/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/contact-centers/*/recordings/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/screen-recordings/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/certificates" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_READ,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/certificatepems" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_READ,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkcertificate" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_UPLOAD,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkkey" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_UPLOAD,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addcertificateandkey" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_UPLOAD,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/removecertificateandkey" access="ROLE_RECORD_KEY_UPLOAD,ROLE_DEFAULT_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/version" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <!-- All URLs should be covered above, it's error if we match this one -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_NOMATCH" />

    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="999999" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
    </security:session-management>

    <security:http-basic />

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref='rcsAuthenticationProvider'/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

RequestMethodMatcher.java

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@AllArgsConstructor
 public class RequestMethodMatcher implements RequestMatcher
{

final private String method;

final private boolean matchIfEqual;

@Override
public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return method.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) == matchIfEqual;
}
}
```

Comment: have you update all your spring-security dependencies ? spring-security-web also ?  make a mvn dependency:tree to see if you still dont have a dependency on spring security 3

Comment: yes all the security dependency has been updated to 4.1.5 including spring-security-web.I have checked the dependency tree.It does not hold spring security 3 references